# Pushing a view controller using Swift 4 after Google Sign In

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase and Swift 4 to develop my app, but I'm having trouble pushing a new view controller after Google Sign In finishes. From what I know, I should be putting the pushViewController code in the didSignIn method, but that section is in my AppDelegate.swift file (as it implements GIDSignInDelegate, as per the Firebase documentation).

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
    // ...
    if let error = error {
        // ...
        return
    }

    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                   accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
    // ...
}
```

Now, I want to push a new view controller after the sign in finishes, using something like:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(BrowserViewController(), animated: true)
```

But it seems impossible to push a VC from the AppDelegate file since navigationController wouldn't exist there. I'm creating my views programmatically without using Storyboards, so I can't perform segues either.

How would I be able to present a new VC after user finishes signing in using Google Sign In? Should I move the didSignInFor method to the view controller that actually hosts the sign in button (even if the documentation doesn't seem to say that this is the right way to do it)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use Notification center to post a notification from your app delegate when the sign in is successful, and then observe this notification in the view controller that hosts the signin button.

Here is an example in swift 4:

In your app delegate in the didSignInFor method:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
    // ...
    if let error = error {
        // ...
        return
    }

    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                   accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
    // ...

    NotificationCenter.default.post(
        name: Notification.Name("SuccessfulSignInNotification"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
}
```

In the ViewController that hosts the signin button:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didSignIn), name: NSNotification.Name("SuccessfulSignInNotification"), object: nil)

}

@objc func didSignIn()  {

    // Add your code here to push the new view controller
  navigationController?.pushViewController(BrowserViewController(), animated: true)

}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

If you want to also handle failed login attemts you can use the same trick and post a notification for failure then observe it in the view controller. Or you can also use one notification for both cases (Success and failure) and in each case you pass a different value.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! I haven't thought of this before -- definitely a creative solution to the issue!

Comment: Very creative solution! Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 0):

If i'm getting your question correctly, Please try to create a navigation controller in app delegate and assign that to window then you can push to individual `viewcontroller` by using push to view controller.

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(BrowserViewController(), animated: true)
```

**For Reference:**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
 {

    // Main Nevigation view controller maintained stack
    var navigationController: UINavigationController!
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        // Home Screen view Object
        let homeVC = HomeVC.init(nibName: "HomeVC", bundle: nil)

        // Allocate navigation controller
        self.navigationController = 
          UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVC)
                return true

       // Custom navigation View Assign window root view controller.
        self.window?.rootViewController = self.navigationController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```