# How to present/perform main view controller after Firebase sign in successful?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-signin

My storyboard flow like this:

`` LaunchViewController -> LoginViewController(with google sign in) -> LocationViewController(for location permission) -> TabBarController -> NavigationController -> If `user logged in and allow to location permission` it will show RestaurantsTableViewController -> DetailViewController `` of restaurants.

When user comes to the `LoginScreen`, google sign in alert pops up and when user allows it, google's sign in screen shows up. After  successfully login in google's custom sign in screen to google account I should present or perform my `LocationViewController`.

I tried this [Swift: Go to other view controller after Google Sign In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55215761/swift-go-to-other-view-controller-after-google-sign-in) and this [Pushing a view controller using Swift 4 after Google Sign In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50549362/pushing-a-view-controller-using-swift-4-after-google-sign-in) answers but did not reach any solve.

My last tried code is like:

**LoginViewController**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.clientID = MyConstants.googleClientID
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = (self as! GIDSignInUIDelegate)
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()

NetworkManager.isUnreachable { _ in
self.showOfflinePage()
}
}

@IBAction func googleSignInTapped(_ sender: Any) { }

private func showOfflinePage() -> Void {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NetworkUnavailable", sender: self)
}
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

    if let error = error {
        print("Firebase sign in error: \(error)")
        return
    }
```

I tried present or perform view controllers after **`else`** block

```
    else {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let nav = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationController") as! UINavigationController
    self.present(nav, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken:  authentication.idToken,
    accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Firebase sign in error: \(error)")
            return
        } else {
            let locationViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LocationViewController")
            self.present(locationViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
} 
}
```

In the **`AppDelegate`** I tried:

```
extension AppDelegate: GIDSignInDelegate {

//MARK: - Firebase
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL?,
                                             sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                             annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                             sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                             annotation: annotation)
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {
if let error = error {
print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
} else {
let userId = user.userID                  
let idToken = user.authentication.idToken
let fullName = user.profile.name
let givenName = user.profile.givenName
let familyName = user.profile.familyName
let email = user.profile.email
}
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!,
withError error: Error!) {  }
}
```

In the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I set the `rootViewController`to LoginViewController:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

self.window.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as? LoginViewController
Firebase.configure()  
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = MyConstants.googleClientID
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self  
}
```

If I try with `present()` function does not anything:

Otherwise with navigation controllers I am getting this error:

**`whose view is not in the window hierarchy`**

Comment: tried to see if error is here `print("Firebase sign in error: \(error)")`

Comment: sign in successful. So nothing show in debug console when searching like `Firebase sign in error:`

Comment: set break point in `let locationViewController =` and check if points/not

Comment: I setted breakpoint but it is not enter this block. I already signed in an google account and I suspected about it and click to sign in alert verify in add new account added new account but nothing change too. It does not enter `let locationViewController` line

Comment: Auth.auth.signIn() is an async method and only runs its completion block when it is done signing in the user. You are presenting the Navigation Controller before the function can complete and run the completion block. This should be why the LocationViewController is not being presented.

Comment: I tried remove else condition navigation code block and close the else block `}`after `Auth.auth` block. Nothing changed how can I refactor it? @nathan-levitt

Comment: I would move the present navigation controller code to the location view controller. It seems like you want to present the navigation controller after you present the location controller right? If you need me to refactor it for visualization purposes I can.

Comment: Yes storyboard sequence like : LaunchScreen->LoginScreen->LocationPermissionScreen->TabbarController->NavigationController->RestaurantsTableViewController. I changed my login system to normal email password login instead of google sign in.

Comment: Here is my storyboard image. https://github.com/emrdgrmnci/Locally/blob/master/Screen%20Shot%202019-07-13%20at%2019.42.23.png